# How to change font color to white in the smartdiagram package?

Tags: fonts, color, smartdiagram

I want to change the font color from gray to white in the smartdiagram package so that in case it is printed b&w it is more readable. This is my current code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{
bubble center node font = \footnotesize,
bubble node font = \footnotesize,
bubble center node size = 0.6cm,
bubble node size = 0.3cm,
distance center/other bubbles = 0.6cm,
distance text center bubble = 0.5cm,
bubble center node color = blue,
set color list = {red, orange, green},
bubble fill opacity = 1,
bubble text opacity = 1,
text color = white
}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
    \textbf{AAA}\\\textbf{BBB},
    \textbf{CCC}
}

\end{document}
```

The text color = white line should take care of it, but it doesn't. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please make your example compilable (full MWE).

Comment: `text color` isn't supported for this type of diagram, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be no `bubble text` key. As a workaround you can use `\tikzset` to add `text=white` to the settings for `bubble center node` and `bubble node`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{
bubble center node font = \footnotesize,
bubble node font = \footnotesize,
bubble center node size = 0.6cm,
bubble node size = 0.3cm,
distance center/other bubbles = 0.6cm,
distance text center bubble = 0.5cm,
bubble center node color = blue,
set color list = {red, orange, green},
bubble fill opacity = 1,
bubble text opacity = 1
}
\tikzset{
bubble center node/.append style={text=white},
bubble node/.append style={text=white}
}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
    \textbf{AAA}\\\textbf{BBB},
    \textbf{CCC}
}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`text color` is not supported for `bubble` type diagrams. However, you can add `\color{white}` to `bubble node font` and `bubble center node font`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{
  bubble center node font = \footnotesize\color{white}\bfseries,
  bubble node font = \footnotesize\color{white}\bfseries,
  bubble center node size = 0.6cm,
  bubble node size = 0.3cm,
  distance center/other bubbles = 0.6cm,
  distance text center bubble = 0.5cm,
  bubble center node color = blue,
  set color list = {red, orange, green},
  bubble fill opacity = 1,
  bubble text opacity = 1,
}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
    AAA\\BBB,
    CCC
}

\end{document}
```

[image: white text]